# redis storing json data with hget command .while fetching forced to fetch all json data in place of single json variable

Tags: python, json, django, redis

I am using Redis to store cache data with my django project.
Below is the code to set cache data into Redis.

```
red = redis.Redis(host=REDIS_HOST, port=REDIS_PORT, db=5, socket_timeout=2)
pip = red.pipeline()
cached_page = {}
cached_page['content'] = page.content
cached_page['header'] = page._headers
cached_page['has_tag'] = False
cached_page = json.dumps(cached_page)
pip.hset(url, 'cached_page', cached_page)
pip.execute()
```

It is working Fine i am able to set data into redis successfully.
Now i want to update value of `has_pag` to True at some condition in my project.
Below is the code i am using to update `has_tag` value to True.

```
cached_page = red.hget(url, 'cached_page')
cached_page = json.loads(cached_page)
_content = cached_page[u'content']
_headers = cached_page[u'header']
red = redis.Redis(host=REDIS_HOST, port=REDIS_PORT, db=5, socket_timeout=2)
pip = red.pipeline()
cached_page = {}
cached_page['content'] = _content
cached_page['header'] = _header
cached_page['has_tag'] = True
cached_page = json.dumps(cached_page)
pip.hset(url, 'cached_page', cached_page)
pip.execute()
```

It is also working fine but i do not want to get content and header when i am fetching data from Redis.
Please give me a efficient solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use hashes to store dicts in redis, than you can update only one key/value from cached_page.

```
In [1]: import redis

In [2]: pool = redis.ConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)

In [3]: r = redis.Redis(connection_pool=pool)

In [4]: r.hmset('test', {1: 'a', 2: 'b'})
Out[4]: True

In [5]: r.hset('test', 2, 'c')
Out[5]: 0L

In [6]: r.hget('test', 2)
Out[6]: 'c'
```

Answer (score 0):

Redis does not support nested hashes, but you can change your data model to emulate them.

The straightforward solution is to store the 'cached_page' as a separate hash entry and change the key to incorporate both the type and the url (for example by adding a prefix), so changing the tag would look like:

```
red = redis.Redis(host=REDIS_HOST, port=REDIS_PORT, db=5, socket_timeout=2)
red.hset('cached_page:' + url, 'has_tag', True)
```

But redis hashes are [best used for small data](http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization) and you could separate the page contents as a separate key (also by using a prefix) and continue to store other page metadata (headers, has_tag) as a hash.